# Can we export all Dialogflow entities at the same time instead of 1 by 1?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a lot of entities and i would like to export them all. I know i can click the export button next to each entity but that is annoying if i have to do this for each and every one.

Is there a way to export them all at the same time ?

I have tried to export the whole agent, but the entities do no get exported with it (they are mentioned in the Intents file but not in a file on their own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export the entire agent, there will be a folder called `entities` which contain the information for all your Entities. Each Entity Type will have at least two files - one containing general metadata about the Entity Type, and the other containing the langauge-specific entries.

Comment: Yes true! i missed that folder when i extracted the ZIPed file.

Answer (score 0):

When I create a new agent under the same project the entities are available right away!
So no need to import them.

Thats the reason that only intents can be exported/imported.